My form doesn't return any errors in Django
I am a Django developer, and I am trying to put two forms in one HTML file(register and login forms), but when I write an invalid input into them, they don't return any errors.
views.py:
def log(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.POST)
    if 'email' in request.POST:
        regisform = RegisterForms(request.POST)
        if regisform.is_valid():
            print("is valid")
            clean_data = regisform.cleaned_data
            user =User.objects.create_user(username=clean_data['user_name'],password=clean_data['password_2'],email=clean_data['email'])
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request, "شما با موفقیت ثبت نام شدید." )
            Profile.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id).hearts_time = jdatetime.datetime.today()
            send_user_notification(user=user, payload={"head":"تبریک", "body":"به سایت ویکی ریاضی حوش آمدید."}, ttl=10)
            return redirect('home:homepage')
        else:
            print("is not valid.")
    else:

        form = LoginForms(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.data
            print(data)
            print("running")
            try:
                user = authenticate(request, username = data['username'],password=data['password'])
                print(user)
            except:
                user =authenticate(request, email = data['email'],password=data['password'])
                print(user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "شما با موفقیت وارد شدید.","warning")
            else:
                print('NOT LOGIN')
            return redirect('home:homepage')
    

else:
    print("Naderi")
    form = LoginForms()
    regisform = RegisterForms()
try:

    content = {
        'form':form,
        'regist':regisform,
    }
except:
    content = {
        'regist':regisform,
    }
return render(request, 'accounts/login.html',content)

forms.py:
class RegisterForms(forms.Form):
user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":'username'}))
password_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'password'}))
password_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Confirm password'}))
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email'}))
captcha = ReCaptchaField(widget=ReCaptchaV2Checkbox)
def clean_password_2(self):
    print('func 1 is begining.')
    password1 = self.cleaned_data['password_1']
    password2 = self.cleaned_data['password_2']
    listletter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    listletterc = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    adad = '1234567890'
    print(password1,password2)
    if password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError('the passwords are not equal.')
    elif len(password2)< 6:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Short Password.')
    small = 0
    cap = 0
    ada = 0
    for i in range(26):
        letter = listletter[i]
        capp = listletterc[i]
        if letter in password2:
            small += 1
        if capp in password2:
            cap += 1
    for i in range(10):
        num = adad[i]
        if num in password2:
            ada += 1
    if small == 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('do not use the small letters.')
    if cap == 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('do not use the capital letters.')
    if ada == 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('do not use numbers.')
    
def clean_user_name(self):
    print('un')
    usern = self.cleaned_data['user_name']
    print(usern)
    if User.objects.filter(username = usern).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Please choose another username.')

and login forms:
class LoginForms(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'username','placeholder':'Username'}))
password = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'password','placeholder':'Password'}))
captcha = ReCaptchaField(widget=ReCaptchaV2Checkbox)

about the html file:
    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64d58efce2.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lanandsign.css' %}" />
    <title>Sign in & Sign up Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="forms-container">
        <div class="signin-signup">
          <form action="" class="sign-in-form" method="post">
            <h2 class="title">Sign in</h2>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              {{ form.username }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              {{form.password}}
            </div>

              {{form.captcha}}

            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn solid">            
            <p class="social-text">Or Sign in with social platforms</p>
            <div class="social-media">
              <a href="{% url "accounts:Send_mail_resetpassword" %}" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
          <form action="" class="sign-up-form" method="post">
            <h2 class="title">Sign up</h2>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              {{ regist.user_name }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              {{regist.password_1}}
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              {{regist.password_2}}
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              {{regist.email}}
            </div>
              {{regist.captcha}}
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn solid">
          
            <p class="social-text">Or Sign up with social platforms</p>
            <div class="social-media">
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panels-container">
        <div class="panel left-panel">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>New here ?</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis,
              ex ratione. Aliquid!
            </p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-up-btn">
              Sign up
            </button>
          </div>
          <img src="img/log.svg" class="image" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel right-panel">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>One of us ?</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum
              laboriosam ad deleniti.
            </p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-in-btn">
              Sign in
            </button>
          </div>
          <img src="img/register.svg" class="image" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'lanandsign.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>

What is the problem? About what file? Please answer quickly.
I am using MySql for database and Django                   4.2.6.
